# XAMPP: Only one usage of each socket addres

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I have created a local php server using XAMPP, for my app to consume.
My app makes a request every second to a php file to check if there is something to do. I've noticed that if I run multiple instantnces of my app, sometimes it starts returning this error:

> **Warning**:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Only one
>   usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted.  in **C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject\common.php**
>   on line **2**
>  
>  **Warning**:  mysqli_query():
>   Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject\signal_update.php** on line
>   **2**
>  
>  **Warning**:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject

The code to connect to the BD is the following:

```
function openCon()
{
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";
  $db = "test_database";
  $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);
  return $conn;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost or maybe `p:127.0.0.1` for a persistent connection.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "mysqli::real\_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only ... permitted."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043528/error-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-only-permitted)

Comment: I have tried using 127.0.0.1 but it still happens. I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve any configuration by a client

Comment: Chaning the regedit to increase max ports seems to work, but is there another solution, like chaning the code or something? Right now it's creating a new connection at every php call, I don't know if this is the right way to do it or not